# MS Access - Find duplicates by non-unique field

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

I've got a problem with duplicates in MS ACCESS 2013 and none of the other posts here have been able to solve it.

I've got a list of customers with a CustomerID, Lastname, Firstname, ..., and a contract number all in one database. (it comes from an external datasource, so I cannot alter it)

The problem is that one customer can have multiple contracts, so there might be multiple entries with the same CustomerID, but with a different contract number.
I want each customer ID to only show up once.

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, Name, FirstName, ContractNumber
FROM tblCustomers;
```

But that doesn't do anything, since the DISTINCT seems to only look for full duplicate rows.

Is there a way I can display every CustomerID only once without getting rid of the Name, FirstName and ContractNumber in the query?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose wich one contactnumber you want to see.
Here is an easiest aproach, just select one that is bigger:

```
select customerid, name, firstname, max(contractnumber)
from tblcustomers
group by customerid, name, firstname
```

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

select customerid, name, firstname, contractnumber
from tblcustomers
group by customerid, name, firstname

Result will look like:

1 Dex Hsu 1234

1 Dex Hsu 5678

1 Dex Hsu 3456

2 Eric Tang 1234

2 Eric Tang 2345

3 Jason Chang 3453

3 Jason Chang 9493